Four fours, except with 1 1 2 2
As the title says, this is the Four Fours puzzle, except with the digits 1, 1, 2, 2. For those who aren't familiar, the goal is to make positive integers using at most two 1's, at most two 2's, and a predetermined set of operations. The following operations are allowed:

+, -, *, /, parentheses
the negative sign
arbitrary exponents and arbitrary roots (where you need to make both numbers, and where the nth root of m is defined as m^(1/n))
square roots (without needing a 2)
factorials
concatenation of two or more of the digits (i.e. no concatenation after performing other operations)
the decimal point, with similar rules (i.e. you can make 12.2 or .212 with a 1, 2, and 2)
the overline to form repeating decimals

In short, anything you can write down with only the digits 1, 1, 2, 2, not necessarily in order, using standard mathematical notation and without using (too) special functions.
With these rules, make 17, 34, 51, and 68.
Bonus: Of the numbers from 1 to 100, 85 is unsolved, as are 46 and 77. Are these possible?

Also, can the numbers be rearranged (i.e. not in the order 1122)?

I assume they can, because of the .212 example.

Does 'factorial' include double!! and triple!!! factorials?

Update: I have solved $77$ now without the triple factorial

 $ 77 = (1 + (\sqrt[\sqrt{.\overline{1}}]{2})!!) \times .2 $

I can solve $77$ but only with double and triple factorials

 $ 77 = ((2 + 2)!!)!!! - \sqrt{1 \ / \ .\overline{1}} $


[ROT18] 32 pna or znqr sebz 36, naq 48 pna or znqr sebz 86.

And then any number is possible with the right multifactorial. e.g. up to 360 with (1+2)! ! = 720 and using 720!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!/720 with the right amount of !.

@Retudin I've got it down to the more reasonable double factorial, which is the only one that needed it, having now solved all the others (without cribbing).

That is a nice one!

I solved all of 17, 34, 51, and 68:

 \begin{align} 17 &= 11+\left(\!\sqrt{2/.\!\bar{2}}\right)! \\ 34 &= {\left(\left(\!\sqrt{1/.\!\bar{1}}\right)!\right)}^{\!2}-2 \\ 51 &= .1^{-2}/2+1 \\ 68 &= .1^{-2}-\sqrt[.1]{\sqrt{2}} \end{align}

I can also solve 46 and 85 in the bonus:

 \begin{align} 46 &= \frac{1/.\!\bar{1}+.2}{.2} \\ 85 &= \frac{2/.\!\bar{1}-1}{.2} \end{align}

Just for fun, here's everything from 1 to 100 (except 77):

 \begin{align} 1 &= 1 \\ 2 &= 2 \\ 3 &= 1+2 \\ 4 &= 2+2 \\ 5 &= 1/.2 \\ 6 &= (1+2)! \\ 7 &= 1+(1+2)! \\ 8 &= 1/.1-2 \\ 9 &= 11-2 \\ 10 &= 1/.1 \\ 11 &= 11 \\ 12 &= 12 \\ 13 &= 1+12 \\ 14 &= 12+2 \\ 15 &= 1+12+2 \\ 16 &= (1+1)^{2+2} \\ \color{blue}{ 17 }&\color{blue}{=} \color{blue}{11+\left(\!\sqrt{2/.\!\bar{2}}\right)!} \\ 18 &= 1/.1\cdot 2-2 \\ 19 &= 1/.1+2/.\!\bar{2} \\ 20 &= 1/.1\cdot 2 \\ 21 &= -1+22 \\ 22 &= 22 \\ 23 &= 1+22 \\ 24 &= (2+2)! \\ 25 &= 1+(2+2)! \\ 26 &= 1+1+(2+2)! \\ 27 &= \left(\!\sqrt{1/.\!\bar{1}}\right)^{\!\sqrt{2/.\!\bar{2}}} \\ 28 &= \left(\!\sqrt{1/.\!\bar{1}}\right)!+22 \\ 29 &= \sqrt[.2]{2}-\!\sqrt{1/.\!\bar{1}} \\ 30 &= \sqrt[.1]{\sqrt{2}} \\ 31 &= \sqrt[.2]{2}-1 \\ 32 &= \sqrt[.2]{2} \\ 33 &= 11+22 \\ \color{blue}{ 34 }&\color{blue}{=} \color{blue}{\left(\left(\!\sqrt{1/.\!\bar{1}}\right)!\right)^2-2} \\ 35 &= \sqrt{1/.\!\bar{1}}+\sqrt[.2]{2} \\ 36 &= \left(\left(\!\sqrt{1/.\!\bar{1}}\right)!\right)^2 \\ 37 &= \sqrt[.1]{\sqrt{2}}+1/.2 \\ 38 &= \left(\left(\!\sqrt{1/.\!\bar{1}}\right)!\right)^2+2 \\ 39 &= (2+2)/.1-1 \\ 40 &= 1/.1\cdot 2\cdot 2 \\ 41 &= 21\cdot 2-1 \\ 42 &= 21\cdot 2 \\ 43 &= 21\cdot 2+1 \\ 44 &= 11\cdot 2\cdot 2 \\ 45 &= 1/.\!\bar{1}/.2 \\ \color{red}{ 46 }&\color{red}{=} \color{red}{(1/.\!\bar{1}+.2)/.2} \\ 47 &= 1/.\!\bar{1}/.2+2 \\ 48 &= (1+1)\cdot (2+2)! \\ 49 &= .1^{-2}/2-1 \\ 50 &= .1^{-2}/2 \\ \color{blue}{ 51 }&\color{blue}{=} \color{blue}{.1^{-2}/2+1} \\ 52 &= 1/.1/.2+2 \\ 53 &= 11/.2-2 \\ 54 &= 12/.\!\bar{2} \\ 55 &= 11/.2 \\ 56 &= 112/2 \\ 57 &= 11/.2+2 \\ 58 &= ((2+1)!-.2)/.1 \\ 59 &= 12/.2-1 \\ 60 &= 12/.2 \\ 61 &= 12/.2+1 \\ 62 &= \left(\sqrt[.1]{\sqrt{2}}-1\right)\cdot 2 \\ 63 &= \sqrt[.1]{\sqrt{2}}\cdot 2-1 \\ 64 &= \sqrt[.1]{\sqrt{2}}\cdot 2 \\ 65 &= \sqrt[.1]{\sqrt{2}}\cdot 2+1 \\ 66 &= \sqrt{1/.\!\bar{1}}\cdot 22 \\ 67 &= 22/\sqrt{.\!\bar{1}}+1 \\ \color{blue}{ 68 }&\color{blue}{=} \color{blue}{.1^{-2}-\sqrt[.1]{\sqrt{2}}} \\ 69 &= (22+1)/\sqrt{.\!\bar{1}} \\ 70 &= \left(\left(\sqrt{1/.\!\bar{1}}\right)!+1\right)\!/.1 \\ 71 &= (2+2)!/\sqrt{.\!\bar{1}}-1 \\ 72 &= (2+2)!/\sqrt{.\!\bar{1}} \\ 73 &= (2+2)!/\sqrt{.\!\bar{1}}+1 \\ 74 &= \left(\sqrt[\sqrt{.\bar{1}}\,]{\sqrt{2}}\right)\!/.\!\bar{1}+2 \\ 75 &= ((2+2)!+1)/\sqrt{.\!\bar{1}} \\ 76 &= {}.\!\bar{1}^{-2}-1/.2 \\ \color{red}{ 77 }&\color{red}{=} {}\color{red}{???} \\ 78 &= {}.\!\bar{1}^{-2}-1-2 \\ 79 &= {}.\!\bar{1}^{-2}-2 \\ 80 &= {}.\!\bar{1}^{-2}-1 \\ 81 &= {}.\!\bar{1}^{-2} \\ 82 &= {}.\!\bar{1}^{-2}+1 \\ 83 &= {}.\!\bar{1}^{-2}+2 \\ 84 &= {}.\!\bar{1}^{-2}+1+2 \\ \color{red}{ 85 }&\color{red}{=} \color{red}{(2/.\!\bar{1}-1)/.2} \\ 86 &= {}.\!\bar{1}^{-2}+1/.2 \\ 87 &= {}.\!\bar{1}^{-2}+(1+2)! \\ 88 &= .1^{-2}-12 \\ 89 &= {}.\!\bar{1}^{-2}+\sqrt[\sqrt{.\bar{1}}\,]{\sqrt{2}} \\ 90 &= 1/.\!\bar{1}\cdot 2/.2 \\ 91 &= 2/.2/.\!\bar{1}+1 \\ 92 &= .1^{-2}-\sqrt[\sqrt{.\bar{1}}\,]{\sqrt{2}} \\ 93 &= \left(\sqrt[.2]{2}-1\right)\!/\sqrt{.\!\bar{1}} \\ 94 &= .1^{-2}-(1+2)! \\ 95 &= .1^{-2}-1/.2 \\ 96 &= (1/.2)!\cdot (1-.2) \\ 97 &= .1^{-2}-1-2 \\ 98 &= .1^{-2}-2 \\ 99 &= 11/.\!\bar{2}\cdot 2 \\ 100 &= .1^{-2} \end{align}

